# Template classes and separate files

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Why won't this code link when compiled in separate files demonstrated here.  Here is the compilation line

```
g++ ./templateC.cpp ./main.cpp
```

here is the error

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `templateC<int>::templateC()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I always thought you could place the implementation in a separate file than the class.  If I can't, why is that?

All files are watered down to prevent confusion, but were compiled with the error as shown here.

Here are my files

main.cpp

```
#include "templateC.h"

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    templateC<int> t;
}
```

templateC.h

```
template<class T>
class templateC
{
    public:
        templateC();
};
```

and templateC.cpp

```
#include "templateC.h"

template<class T>
templateC<T>::templateC()
{

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13

Comment: I read through it, why must that be done, is it a bug in the linker?

Comment: @MadKeithV You're right I didn't see that post, should I delete the question or link to it?

Comment: @rubixibuc: no need to delete your question. Having duplicates is not such a bad thing, it makes the "original" question easier to find through search engines. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates) for a reference for this, there are many more on [meta].